# Prove absolute sum expectation

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, central-limit-theorem

I have encountered the following problem, could someone provide me some hints on how to solve it?

> Assume that the sequence $(X_n)$ is i.i.d. with mean $0$ and variance $1$. For every $n\ge1$, let $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$. Then,
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\ E|S_n|=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}.$$

Comment: Hints: $\sum_i X_i$ has $0$ mean and variance $n$. The CLT says that the CDF of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is converging to the CDF of a $N(0,1)$ random variable as $n\to\infty$. For a nonnegative random variable $Y$ such as $\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right|$, $\displaystyle E[Y] = \int_0^\infty [1-F_Y(y)]\,\mathrm dy$

Answer (score 0):

Define $Y_n:=n^{-1/2} \left|S_n \right|$ and $Z$ a random variable of standard normal distribution. Then for a fixed $R$, 
$$ \left|\mathbb E(Y_n)-\mathbb E(Z)\right| 
\leqslant  \int_0^R \left|\mathbb P\{Y_n \gt t\}-\mathbb P\{Z \gt t\}\right|\mathrm dt+ \int_R^{+\infty}\mathbb P\{Y_n \gt t\}\mathrm dt+\int_R^{+\infty}\mathbb P\{Z \gt t\}\mathrm dt.$$
Since $ \mathbb E [Y_n^2 ]=1$, we get by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$\int_R^{+\infty}\mathbb P\{Y_n \gt t\}\mathrm dt=\int_R^{+\infty}\mathbb P\{Y_n \mathbf 1 \{Y_n \gt R\} \gt t\}\mathrm dt \leqslant \mathbb E\left[Y_n\mathbf 1 \{Y_n \gt R\}\right] \leqslant  \mu\{Y_n \gt R\}^{1/2}$$
we obtain by Markov's inequality
$$\int_R^{+\infty}\mathbb P\{Y_n \gt t\}\mathrm dt \leqslant \frac 1R,$$
and a similar estimate holds for $Z$. In view of the first displayed equation, it follows that 
$$ \tag{*}\left|\mathbb E(Y_n)-\mathbb E(Z)\right| \leqslant 
R \sup_{t\in [-R,R ] }\left|\mathbb P\{Y_n \gt t\}-\mathbb P\{Z \gt t\}\right|+ \frac 2R.$$
Since the distribution function of $Z$ is continuous, the first term of (*) converges to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.